# Opening preexisting jupyter notebook in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I'm trying to run a downloaded jupyter notebook from https://github.com/justmarkham/scikit-learn-videos with pycharm 16.1 on win7. I've come across https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/tutorial-using-ipython-jupyter-notebook-with-pycharm.html , but this appears to deal with creating a notebook from scratch. Following the directions, I have created a virtualenv 'ml' with scikit learn and the needed depedencies including the jupyter notebook. As you can see, the main project run button is greyed out. Do I need to create a configuration file for this, i.e.

[image]

How can I get this working?

Comment: I am on macOS, but had no problems running this just now. First of all, are you running a jupyter notebook server?